# How can you ensure element positioning using in-line styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I've developed a web page that has an image element I've applied relative positioning to position the element just the right distance from the left side of the page.

During my testing, I've view the site using IE8 (although it will not be officially supported), IE9, Firefox and Chrome. The page renders reasonably well with exception for some slight pixel differentials between the browsers; but nothing drastic. These systems were tested using a max screen resolution of 1280 x 1040

The problem I'm trying to solve is when the site is viewed on a Mac having the screen resolution of 1920 x 1200 the image gets positioned way outside the site layout. Resizing the Safari browser window slowly brings the element back into its desired position but users shouldn't have to do that.

The element is wrapped in this div tag and resides inside a table element like this.

```
<div style="position:relative;right:-200px;top:0px;" >
     <img src="/Images/member_platinum.png" height="80" width="100" />
</div>
```

Is there another way to position the element that will retain its position irrelevant of the screen resolution other that using position:absolute? I don't want to use absolute positioning as it doesn't produce the correct rendered affect.

Or should I maybe be rendering the element based on the Screen Resolution using some javascripting?

But my problem with that approach is that all the other elements render appropriately and retain their positions except for that one and this one as well.

```
<style>
#adjacentPrivate div { 
    margin-left: 5px; 
    float: left; 
}
</style>

<div id="adjacentPrivate" style="position:relative;left:-560px;top:30px;">
<div id="rating2" style="font-weight:bold;color:#666;font-size:14px;position:relative;top:-30px;">@TempData["UserRatingText"]</div>
<div id="yourRating" style="position:relative;margin-left:15px;width:200px;top: 30px;"></div>
</div>
<div style="position:relative;left:10px;">
    <script>
       $('#yourRating').raty({ readOnly: Boolean("@TempData["CanVote"]"), score: parseInt('@TempData["CurrentRating"]'), click: function (score, evt) { setRating(score); } });
    </script>
</div>
```

So it may be the way I am styling my elements. I am no CSS expert so is there a better way to achieve the desired result strictly using in-line styling or CSS? Or is element positioning based on Screen Resolution the way to go???

Comment: Position relative, in it's raw state, will only move elements in relation to their natural positioning. Without seeing what it is you are trying to achieve it's hard to help. Perhaps a reduced case JSfiddle? Also, inline styling should be abstracted to a CSS styleseeht.

Comment: I can certainly try creating a reduced case of the issue and post it to JSFiddle. I will respond back once I've posted it. Thanks

Comment: Ok. So this is the best I can do for a stripped down version of the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/9UgYs/10/embedded/result/  I am view the resulting output in Chrome with a 1280 x 1040 resolution and the browser not being resizable (full size view). If you look at the cell containing the contact information, the image will appear in the lower right corner of the cell. But to emulate what happens on a Mac (1920 x 1200 resolution); if you resize the width of the browser the image will fall far outside the cell to the right.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help - http://jsfiddle.net/fw6yr/ - but I've done it all in a div, placed the text in spans and absolutely positioned the icon.

Comment: Thanks TimeSPQR. That actually will work as it will keep the image confined within the constraints of the holder. I will give you credit for the answer if you propose it as one, but it would be nice if you wouldn't mind giving a very general explanation as to why your solution works but mine did not. As I pointed out earlier, I am not an expert in CSS so an explanation would help me understand the principle so I may employ it appropriately in the future as opposed to copying code without fully knowing why it works. Thanks!